# How to reference maya commands in VS Code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, maya

I installed the 'MayaCode'pack in VS code. I want to use this. But.... I can't use the function 'Send Python Code to maya', I get an error. I want to solve this.
Hellp me..

And How do it;; Debugging error

### import maya.cmds as cmds

** ImportError: No module named maya.cmds **